# How does javascript's split function work through the delimiters if multiple delimiters are specified

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am splitting a string using Javascript's split function with multiple delimiters. Although I get it to work, its behavior puzzles me. Looking for an explanation to this behavior

I have this string below --

```
let z = 'c4 <= v4';
```

I split it with `console.log(z.split(/(<|=|<=)/))`. The string might potentially contain `<`, `=`, or `<=`, which is why I am splitting it with 3 delimiters.
This give me `[ 'c4 ', '<', '', '=', ' v4' ]`, which isn't what I am expecting. I was expecting `[ 'c4 ', '<=', ' v4' ]`.

Then I figure split is going down the list of delimiters, so it first split by `<`, then split the result by `=`, which would explain the empty element between < and =. Then when it get to delimiter `<=`, it couldn't find any in the result.

So to prove my thinking, I tried `console.log(z.split(/(=|<=)/))`.
Following my logic, I was expecting the result to be `[ 'c4 <', '=', ' v4' ]`, since I was expecting split to use `=` first as delimiter.
However, the actual result is `[ 'c4 ', '<=', ' v4' ]`. Almost as if split just skipped over the delimiter `=`.

I can get it to work correctly if I arrange the order of the delimiters `console.log(z.split(/(<=|<|=)/))`, and will get `[ 'c4 ', '<=', ' v4' ]` which sort of re-enforces my thinking, since `<=` is the first delimiter specified.

I searched a whole bunch, and couldn't find an explanation to this behavior. How does split work through the delimiters?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the implementation, but notice that, in your second case, the function going through the string would reach the position before `<`, check if the expression can be satisfied there, and use the valid `<=` option.

Comment: This isn't so much about how `.split()` works as it is about how regular expression matching works. In general when using a sequence of alternatives separated by `|` in a regex, you have to arrange the alternatives such that longer ones come first when they include a prefix that's also another alternative.

Comment: (Note: this is not a universal Regex behavior, but specific to a particular flavor - thankfully, JS implementations are standardized. There are some implementations that will choose longest-match, eg.)

Comment: @user2864740 yes that's a great point, though not necessarily encouraging for new programmers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of alternates matters here. If you split on `/(<|=|<=)/` it will split at the first match it finds which is the `<`. This means the remaining string no longer has that `<=`, it just has `=` so it splits again on that. If you change the order, you can make sure `<=` matches before `<` and `=` alone:

```js
let z = 'c4 <= v4';
console.log(z.split(/(<=|=|<)/))
```

The case of `/(=|<=)/` is more interesting because it matches the `<=`.

```js
let z = 'c4 <= v4';
console.log(z.split(/(=|<=)/))
```

The reason for this is because regex engine matches eagerly. While scanning the string, the first potential match it sees is `<`. At this point it knows it has a potential match with the `<=` alternative, so if continues to the next character to see if it is in fact a match. It turns out to be so it moves on and considered the match made. It never needs to test `=` alone.

You can avoid all of this if you use something more like: `/([<=]+)/` But that's going to be more forgiving and match any combination of `<` and `=`

```js
let z = 'c4 <= v4 == x4 =< z6 = a9 < b9';
console.log(z.split(/([<=]+)/g))
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking. But how come when I did `z.split(/(=|<=)/)`, I get `[ 'c4 ', '<=', ' v4' ]`? Shouldn't it match `=` first and produce `[ 'c4 <', '=', ' v4' ]`

Comment: Ah. I see what you're asking. A regex engine will work through the text and tokens it's trying to match. So in the above case it see `<` and starts to match the `<=`. It is eager, so it will continue character for character trying to match `<=`. It succeeds here so you never need to check the  `=` alternative.

Comment: @LandCrawler, I added an edit to the post, that I hope explains a bit.

Answer (score 2):

In most regular expression engines, when you have multiple alternatives that can match the same string, it uses the first one that matches. So it makes a difference whether you write `<|<=` or `<=|<`.

If the input string is `foo<=bar`, the first version will match just `<` because it's the first alternative that matches, while the second will match `<=`.

This is explained in more detail at [Regular-Expression.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

So the solution in general is to write your regexp with the alternatives in order by length descending, e.g. `z.split(/(<=|<|=)/)`

There are some regexp engines that always try to find the longest match, rather than the first match (the above page calls them "text-directed"). But JavaScript doesn't do this.

Comment: Thank you. The article is great. I had a further question but Mark clarified it for me.